# App Won't Load After Link /data/app to 2nd SD-Card Partition

Tags: custom-roms, rom, app2sd, link2sd

Lenovo S920
Android 4.2.1

Basically, I want to link my **/data/app** to **/system/sd/app** (2nd SD Card partition).

I have mount my 2nd partition on boot to **/system/sd/app** correctly.

Here what I got when run "mount":

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/emmc@preload /preload ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data
=ordered 0 0
/emmc@android /system ext4 ro,relatime,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0

/emmc@usrdata /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=or
dered 0 0
/emmc@cache /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ord
ered 0 0
/emmc@protect_f /protect_f ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_all
oc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/emmc@protect_s /protect_s ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_all
oc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /system/sd ext2 rw,relatime 0 0 // Mount correctly
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /storage/sdcard1 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,rela
time,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp43 7,ioc
harset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Look at **/dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /system/sd ext2 rw,relatime 0 0**. It looks mount fine.

Here what I got when run "ls -l /data/":

```
-rw------- system system 131072 2015-09-17 15:23 3D.bin
drwxrwx--- bluetooth net_bt 2015-09-17 14:51 @btmtk
-rw-rw---- nvram nvram 34466 2015-09-17 14:31 AllFile
-rw-rw---- nvram nvram 14600 2015-09-17 14:31 AllMap
-rw-rw-r-- nvram nvram 30 2015-09-17 15:05 BT_Addr
-rw-r--r-- root root 80 2015-09-17 15:05 Test.log
drwxr-xr-x root root 2015-09-17 15:16 aee_exp
drwxrwx--x gps system 2015-09-17 15:05 agps_supl
drwxrwx--- system system 2015-09-17 14:31 amit
drwxrwxr-x system system 2015-09-17 15:05 anr
lrwxrwxrwx root root 2015-09-17 15:12 app -> /system/sd/app
drwx------ root root 2015-09-17 14:31 app-asec
drwxrwx--x system system 2015-09-17 14:49 app-lib
drwxrwx--x system system 2015-09-17 14:31 app-private
-rw------- system system 1048576 2013-09-17 07:00 appbank
drwx------ system system 2015-09-17 14:33 backup
-rw------- system system 0 2015-09-17 14:31 combo_t32.cmm
drwxrwx--x system system 2015-09-17 14:49 dalvik-cache
drwxrwx--x system system 2015-09-17 14:49 data
drwxr-x--- root log 2015-09-17 14:31 dontpanic
drwxrwxr-- drm system 2015-09-17 14:33 drm
-rw------- root root 42 2015-09-17 15:05 etm.backup
-rw------- root root 1238 2015-09-17 15:05 link2sd-debuggerd.log
drwxr-x--x root root 2015-09-17 14:31 local
drwxrwx--- root root 2015-09-17 14:30 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx shell shell 2015-09-17 14:31 mdl
drwxrwx--- media_rw media_rw 2015-09-17 14:31 media
drwxrwx--t system misc 2015-09-17 15:05 misc
drwxrwx--- root nvram 2015-09-17 14:31 nvram
-rw------- system system 4194304 2015-09-17 15:17 piggybank
drwx------ root root 2015-09-17 15:23 property
drwxrwx--x system system 2015-09-17 14:31 resource-cache
srwx------ system system 2015-09-17 15:17 server
drwxr-x--- root shell 2015-09-17 14:31 ssh
drwxrwxr-x system system 2015-09-17 15:35 system
drwx--x--x system system 2015-09-17 14:31 user
```

Look at **lrwxrwxrwx root root 2015-09-17 15:12 app -> /system/sd/app**. It looks linked fine.

Here when I run "ls /system/sd/app":

```
com.UCMobile.intl-1.apk
com.altermyth.bima.tablet-2.apk
com.android.chrome-1.apk
com.android.vending-1.apk
com.appstar.callrecorder-2.apk
com.bbm-2.apk
com.bookmark.money-2.apk
com.cilctel.crono-1.apk
com.estrongs.android.pop-2.apk
com.evernote-1.apk
com.facebook.orca-2.apk
com.google.android.apps.books-1.apk
com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk
com.google.android.apps.plus-1.apk
com.google.android.calendar-2.apk
com.google.android.gm-1.apk
com.google.android.gms-1.apk
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-1.apk
com.google.android.inputmethod.latin-1.apk
com.google.android.play.games-1.apk
com.google.android.talk-1.apk
com.google.android.tts-1.apk
com.google.android.youtube-1.apk
com.hellotext.hello-2.apk
com.instagram.android-2.apk
com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup-1.apk
com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad-2.apk
com.opera.browser-2.apk
com.opera.browser.classic-1.apk
com.shazam.android-2.apk
com.skype.raider-1.apk
com.supercell.clashofclans-2.apk
com.trello-2.apk
com.twitter.android-2.apk
com.whatsapp-2.apk
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail-1.apk
jackpal.androidterm-2.apk
jp.naver.line.android-2.apk
net.openvpn.openvpn-1.apk
org.rojekti.clipper-2.apk
os.tools.scriptmanager-1.apk
```

It seems fine when I first linked it, but after I reboot. It didn't work.

How to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

I test link an *.apk file to `/data/temp/` folder.  `temp` folder is in internal storage. So, it isn't 2nd partition. I just want to make sure that link is work in internal storage, but it seems link failed shown like this:
[image: Symlink Result]

Look at com.dotgears.flappybird-1.apk

When I do `ls -l` in /data/app:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-09-23 07:58 com.dotgears.flappybird-1
.apk -> /data/temp/com.dotgears.flappybird-1.apk
```

Any idea what is going on?

UPDATE:

It seems whatever I copy an *.apk file to new location. It seems failed. It actually not failed but somehow when I properties my *.apk that I copied to new location. I click on it, it show nothing. Like, their **icon didn't show, version: N/A, size: N/A, Package Name: N/A**

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting, any mounts you have made which your ROM isn't configured to automatically do will be lost. You could write your own init.d script, or you could use an app, like [Mounts2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.mounts2sd&hl=en), which will set it up for you and comes with a nice interface to boot.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. That's why I have played with init.d. So when  I reboot I got my 2nd partition mounted correctly. But some how, the system don't load app from linked directory /system/sd/app. I know there are a few app that could solve my problem, but I just want to do by my self for experiment purpose. :) Do you have any clue about my problem?

Comment: It might be that the mount happens too late in the boot process - I couldn't really say, but you could try mounting the second partition directly onto /data/app in your script, rather than using a symlink from /data/app to /system/sd/app.

Comment: I don't won't mount directly to /data/app. Because I have several folder to link to. I do some new experiment above. Please check my update. Maybe you have and idea that could help me.